# Does Lombok @Nonnull also have an effect for e.g. suppliers?

Tags: java, lombok, functional-interface

For the following declaration

```
public static <E extends SomeInterface> E methodName(
    @NonNull Supplier<@NonNull E> supplier,
    Consumer<@NonNull E> consumer)
```

does Lombok automatically null-check the `supplier`s result ?
And/or does it make it make sense for the `consumer` to ensure that the E passed in is null-checked (e.g. by generating a null wrapper)?

Comment: You can easily find this out yourself by writing some code, you know.

Comment: The advantage of this is if the next person has the same question. But good point, let me write a small test , and self-answer.

Comment: Why should it generate a wrapper? It may inject an explicit check if the method makes a `get()` call on that `supplier`, right after the call, but there is no reason to generate a wrapper that would live no longer than the method’s scope.

Comment: @Holger: good point about the wrapper. Edited to hopefully clarify the meaning.

Comment: So it’s a more general question whether Lombok does insert checks to enforce `@NonNull ` at all?

Comment: @Holger: the docs state that some cases are checked. The question was about whether this would apply to other cases as well. Answered awesomely below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, `@NonNull` is purely documentary, except for 2 cases:

- If directly on a parameter (and not on some generics inside a parameter), lombok checks if you have an explicit nullcheck for that parameter at the start of the method somewhere. If you don't, lombok adds one.
- If directly on a field (and not on some generics inside a field's type), any constructors, setters, and withers lombok generates will add a null check for that value.

**That is it**. Lombok does not generate any checks if you stick it on a method / on a return type, for example.

This is intentional, and any PRs to change this behaviour would be denied. (SOURCE: I'm one of the 2 people who makes the final call on such things).

To explain specifically why lombok does not and in fact **cannot** do anything meaningful to `@NonNull` within `<>`:

Imagine you have a method taking an `Iterable<String>`.

What do you expect lombok to do? Call `.iterator()` on the parameter, loop through to the end (keep iterating until `hasNext()` returns `false`), and report if any `.next()` call returns `null`? This:

- requires knowing how `Iterable` works. Lombok cannot encode the sum total knowledge of the entire java ecosystem. At best we can hardcode that we 'know' what the generics mean for well known types and just give up on anything else. And then, I guess, write some sort of plugin system so you can check your own stuff? This is a herculean and complicated affair for.. what, exactly?
- Simply does not work here - you can make iterables that are literally infinite. Lombok would encode an endless loop, in a way that isn't obvious. Obviously highly undesired behaviour.
- Literally mathematically impossible. Imagine a `Supplier<@NonNull String>`. Do we just call it 50 times, check for `null`, and consider 'good enough' after 50 loops? What about a `IntFunction<@NonNull String>`. Do we invoke it with all 4 billion possible `int` values? What about `Function<String, @NonNull String>`? What if this function isn't 'stable'? The docs of `Function` do not require that it is - what if invoking it with some value the first time produces a different result from the second time?

At best lombok can add null checks when you invoke your lambdas inside that method. But this doesn't actually prove much. What if you hand this lambda off to another method? For 'normal' nullity annotations (directly on a parameter), the `@NonNull` guarantees it's right and this guarantee survives passing the variable around. This simply isn't possible with generics.

Comment: Thanks so much for this clear explanation right "from the source".

Comment: It seems that you assume that an injected check must be able to determine the potentially failure even before it happens but this assumption does not hold for the field checks in a constructor anyway. So why not inject a check on the result of the actual `get()`, `next()`, `apply` calls?

Comment: Because that just checks _this_ invocation. It doesn't guarantee the next invocation gets it right. _but this assumption does not hold for the field checks in a constructor anyway._ I don't think I understand the nuance here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It seems similar to the constructor checks: in many cases, as mentioned by Holger above, it should be possible to null-check the result. Of course, this is impossible to ensure e.g. for all elements of a collection, but many generics could possibly be checked this way, right @Holger?

Comment: “Because that just checks this invocation.” Well, yes? That was my point. Even the parameter checks at the beginning of the method, as Lombok injects now, only check *this* invocation and don’t “guarantee the next invocation gets it right”. Each invocation has to be checked, *when it happens*. It’s the same with `get()` etc. The only difference is that the check for `get()` would happen *after* the operation but that’s not different to constructors because fields are `null` initially even if annotated `@NonNull`. You can only spot a missing assignment *after* the constructor execution.

Comment: Imagine a method: `@NonNull String method(@NonNull String param)`. And we have a `void caller() {@NonNull String response = method(localVar);}` someplace. One _could_ suggest the following methodology: "Generate a null check in `caller` to ensure `localVar` really isn't null, _before_ sending it. Because who knows what `method` does? And, when `method` returns, check that it indeed didn't return `null`." And then applying the same 'just check it!' idea to `caller`: It should check if the parameter isn't null (because who knows what callers do), and generate a null check for every `return`.

Comment: But now we have 4(!!!) nullchecks and if both 'edges' of an interaction are this careful in their null checks, they are essentially pointless. The JVM ends up spending 40% of its time on pointless nullchecks. This is nuts. Hence why we (lombok authors) ascribe to a different model: You check parameters of public methods. This fits other established conventions (checking preconditions of params as a general principle). You __do not__ check that API calls do what they say they do, because where does it end? This also avoids nullcheck avalanche.

Comment: The point is: If `null` (or other violations of a contract) occurs anywhere, you optimally want the compiler to tell you as you write it, but, failing that, you want an exception as soon as possible with a stack trace that includes the line of code that is at fault. However, there are limits: There is a line. Checking the contract stipulation 85912 times per second is over the line. If most code checks params, you get your stack trace soon enough. If you want a different world, maybe. But as usual, `null` drives people mental. Nobody does this 'check everything always' for other preconditions.

Answer (score 1):

As [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689909/does-lombok-nonnull-also-have-an-effect-for-e-g-suppliers?noredirect=1#comment136965551_77689909), this can be easily checked: Lombok does not do this. Example test code:

```
   static class NullWrapperTest
   {
      public static void check(@NonNull Supplier<@NonNull Object> supplier,
            Consumer<@NonNull Object> consumer)
      {
         consumer.accept(supplier.get());
      }
   }

   @Test()
   void testNullity()
   {
      assertThatThrownBy(() -> NullWrapperTest.check(() -> null, (param) -> System.out.println(param)));
   }
```

The test fails, no exception is thrown. If you know if this is planned, please add another answer.